# Simple HTML code and integrating CSS, Python, and JavaScript with the existing HTML code

Tags: functional-programming, programming-languages

Tonight I started programming a makeshift webpage thats not really a webpage. I downloaded Notepad++, opened it and started writing HTML code. I am making a table of information that has (at the moment) 5 columns, and there will be a lot more rows but let's say I have 4 for now.

The first part of my question is how do I go about sorting the information in the table? I want to be able to switch between organizing the information in the columns.

My second question is, it seems like I will need to incorporate CSS and/or Jaxascript and/or Python to get more of an animated feel to my makeshift webpage. Can I do that with notepad? Or do I need to download a second program...? How would that work?

Comment: Hello, Welcome to Stack Overflow. First of all, congrats to you for taking the initiative to learn a new language and skill! This site is really intended to help coders address specific issues they are having with specific blocks of code. My best advice for you would be to do a Google search for each question you have asked, then make a concerted attempt to write the code yourself. If you find that you are having trouble with the code, you can come back here, post it, and we can try and help you. Please review the question guide for more e info: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: And yes, you can write HTML, CSS, and JS with Notepad! I personally do it all the time!

Comment: Thank you Russ J. I have tried looking online for the sorting code but I guess I haven't looked deep enough yet. And I guess ill also look up how to add CSS and JS. Thank you very much

Comment: If you're looking for a good tutorial on HTML, CSS, and JS, I would recommend w3schools.com

Comment: Yeah that was pretty much the first thing that popped up from Google. Its a little hard to navigate though but I guess that's cause I'm still new. Ill get the gang of it eventually